# How do you check the internet connection in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, network-state

I want to check the internet connectivity in each activity. If it is lost a message should be displayed.

Can any one guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Try this library that I wrote.

https://github.com/muddassir235/connection_checker

It provides a listener with onConnected, onConnectionSlow and onDisconnected methods.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check the network state.

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
    || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {

    // notify user you are online

}
else if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED 
    || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

    // notify user you are not online
}
```

Note that the constants ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE and ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI represent connection types and these two values are not exhaustive. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType()) for an exhaustive list.

---

Also make sure that you have the required permission to monitor the network state. You need to add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: it is giving me following error 
ConnectivityService: Neither user 10026 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

on conMgr.getNetworkInfo

Comment: You have to add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

Comment: ok one thing i have noticed.. when wifi is connected to wireless modem internet coverage is there or not it always says yes you are conected it only checks wifi conectivity not internet connectivity so how to handle such a situation ?

Comment: This won't work al the time, you need to loop through all the network types: NetworkInfo infos[] = conMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
 for(NetworkInfo info : infos){} around the if, and no else.

Comment: See the response from William for a more concise and "correct" approach. This approach is not exhaustive, as already pointed out.

Comment: wrong code. if the network number 0 is disabled, state of the network 0 will not be checked, but it can be connecting...

Comment: @SarpCentel I've added that permission but it still raised the same error

Comment: Not exhaustive, but sufficient for most cases, unless user is tethering from bluetooth.

Comment: It is deprecated in marshmallow

Answer (score 126):

Only one connection can be active at any one point. So a simpler answer is:

```
final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
    // notify user you are online
} else {
    // notify user you are not online
}
```

It also caters for any new type of network such as ConnectivityManager#TYPE_WIMAX

---

Also make sure that you have the required permission to monitor the network state. You need to add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: There is a method name `isConnected()` for Network info could that replace your line `.getState() == ...` and make it even simpler?

Comment: Nice pick up #bytebender. I have amended the solution. Even simpler now :-)

Comment: Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` to AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 10):

You can do this, for various types of network status

```
public void  checkNetworkStatus(){

    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
     this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

     final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
     connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

     final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
     connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

     if( wifi.isAvailable() ){

     Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else if( mobile.isAvailable() ){

     Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else
     {

         Toast.makeText(this, "No Network " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can check network coverage and data availability of Mobile and wi-fi directly with

For **Network coverage** availability,

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable()
{
 ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkInfo mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
 NetworkInfo wifiNwInfo   = conxMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

return ((mobileNwInfo== null ? false : mobileNwInfo.isAvailable()) || (wifiNwInfo == null ? false : wifiNwInfo.isAvailable()));

}
```

For **Data availability** if network available

```
private boolean isDataAvailable()
{
  ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkInfo mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
 NetworkInfo wifiNwInfo   = conxMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

return ((mobileNwInfo== null? false : mobileNwInfo.isConnected() )|| (wifiNwInfo == null? false : wifiNwInfo.isConnected()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Correction

```
if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
    ||  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING  ) {
   //notify user you are online
}
```

should be

```
if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
    ||  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
    //notify user you are online
}
```

Comment: ok one thing i have noticed.. when wifi is connected to wireless modem internet coverage is there or not it always says yes you are conected it only checks wifi conectivity not internet connectivity so how to handle such a situation ?

Answer (score 3):

Register a broadcast receiver to **handle [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)**. See this [full example](http://code.google.com/p/androidwisprclient/source/browse/trunk/src/com/joan/pruebas/NetworkConnectivityListener.java?r=2). You should update a static variable 'connectionAvailable' that will be accessible everywhere and everytime through its respective getter.

Remember to declare the broadcast receiver in the **manifest** file:

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkConnectivityReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

On the matter of 'checking in each activity', may be you would be interested in using a **BaseActivity extended by your activities** and managing the test of connectivity and displaying the message.

Also, note that **using events** (not polling from activities) will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(0).getState()` and `ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(1).getState()` properly, instead of hardcoding the values (1) and (0) use `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI` and `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE`

Answer (score 0):

This is a boolean check to see if you have network access. It doesn't determine what kind of network access - mobile, wifi..., it just checks to see if you're online.

```
boolean mobileNwInfo = false;  
ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
try { mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected(); }  
catch (NullPointerException e) { mobileNwInfo = false; }  
if ( mobileNwInfo == false ) {
  // Your code goes here...
}
```