# Android - Checking internet connection before starting an intent

Tags: android

I want to check the internet connection before opening an intent. How can I do this? I am a beginner in this field. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check the internet connection in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326767/how-do-you-check-the-internet-connection-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method checks whether mobile is connected to internet and returns true if connected and also you need to update your manifest file

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {

  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)   getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (networkInfo == null) {
      // There are no active networks.
      return false;
  } else
  return true;
 }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: is accessing WIFI_STATE necessary?

Comment: Its optional but you can follow that too

Comment: "ACCESS_WIFI_STATE "Allows applications to access information about Wi-Fi networks

Comment: i did.......... btw accessing network state also checks about wifi networks, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Do add permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConnectivityManager` before starting new Intent, if `isConnectedOrConnecting()` returns `true` you may proceed with `Intent.startActivity()`

Don't forget `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` in Manifest

Have a look at duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326767/how-do-you-check-the-internet-connection-in-android?rq=1) for deeper explanation

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Copy this Function to Your Activity from which you want to Intent.

```
public boolean CheckInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            //we are connected to a network
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }//end of check int
```

Now before Intent Simply call this function in if condition

```
if(CheckInternet()){
Intent intent=new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
else{
Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Don't forget to add these lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks.