# show snackbar if their is no internet connection

Tags: android

here I have an splash activity and here I want that it produce snackbar massage when  their is no internet connection found and also have a retry option in it ....when click the retry it again check intenet connection then go to next activity....help me

```
package com.apkglobal.pocket;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.apkglobal.pocket.R;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent i= new Intent(SplashActivity.this,NavigationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are currently having? I don't see any code where you try and use a snackbar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326767/how-do-you-check-the-internet-connection-in-android

Comment: I m a beginner I don't know how to implement it ..suggest something..

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution for pinging a server, then returning result on main thread

```
    private void showSnackIfOffline(){
    final boolean online = isOnline();
    runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() { //must run on main thread to update UI (show Snackbar), can be used only in Activity (FragmentActivity, AppCompatActivity...)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!online)
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Sorry, you're offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else{
                /*
                    Your code here if user is online
                */
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean isOnline(){
    try {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8").waitFor() == 0; //  "8.8.8.8" is the server to ping
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My example implementation, the notifications of network status with Snackbar in Kotlin. Maybe it will help someone. I did the listener the status of the network. Snackbar POPs up on any screen!

```
interface INetworkAvailabilityNotification {
    fun init()
}

class NetworkAvailabilityNotificationImpl(
        val context: Context,
        private val networkStateProvider: INetworkStateProvider,
        resourcesInteractor: IResourcesInteractor) : INetworkAvailabilityNotification {

private var weekReferenceActivity: WeakReference<Activity>? = null
private var snackbar: Snackbar? = null
private val networkUnavailableText: String by lazy { resourcesInteractor.getString(R.string.network_unavailable_error) }

override fun init() {
    initActivityCallback()
    initOnlineListener()
}

private fun showSnackbar(message: String) {
    initSnackBar()
    setText(message)
    snackbar?.show()
}

private fun setViewParams() {
    snackbar?.let {
        val layoutParams =
                (it.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams)
                        .also { lp -> lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) }
        it.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        it.view.layoutParams = layoutParams
        it.view.alpha = 0.90f
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            it.view.elevation = 0f
        }
    }
}

private fun initActivityCallback() = (context as? Application)?.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacksImpl() {
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity?) {
        activity?.let { weekReferenceActivity = WeakReference(activity) }
    }
})

private fun initSnackBar() = weekReferenceActivity?.get()?.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)?.let { view ->
    if (weekReferenceActivity?.get() is AppCompatActivity) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setBehavior(NoSwipeBehavior())
        setViewParams()
    }
}

private fun initOnlineListener() {
    networkStateProvider.isOnline.observe { isOnline ->
        if (isOnline) snackbar?.dismiss() else showSnackbar(networkUnavailableText)
    }
}

private fun setText(message: String) {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(message).apply {
        setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)), 0, message.length, 0)
    }
    snackbar?.setText(spannableString)
}
}

internal class NoSwipeBehavior : BaseTransientBottomBar.Behavior() {
    override fun canSwipeDismissView(child: View): Boolean = false
}

open class ActivityLifecycleCallbacksImpl : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity?, outState: Bundle?) {}
    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {}
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}

}
```

Network status class

```
interface INetworkStateProvider {
    val stateLiveData: LiveData<SealedNetworkState>
    val isOnline: LiveData<Boolean>
}

class NetworkStateProviderImpl(private val context: Context) : INetworkStateProvider {

    private companion object {
        const val CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
        const val WIFI_STATE_CHANGED = "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"
    }

    private val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    private val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) = this@NetworkStateProviderImpl.onReceive()
    }
    override val stateLiveData: MutableLiveData<SealedNetworkState> = object : MutableLiveData<SealedNetworkState>() {
        override fun onActive() = registerBroadcastReceiver()
        override fun onInactive() = unregisterBroadcastReceiver()
    }
    override val isOnline: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = stateLiveData.map {
        connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected == true
    }.distinctUntilChanged()


    private fun registerBroadcastReceiver() {
        context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE)
            addAction(WIFI_STATE_CHANGED)
        })
    }

    private fun unregisterBroadcastReceiver() = context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)

    private fun getConnectivityStatus(): SealedNetworkState = if (connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected == true) {
        when (connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.type) {
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> SealedNetworkState.NetworkWiFi
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> SealedNetworkState.NetworkMobile
            else -> SealedNetworkState.NetworkOther
        }
    } else SealedNetworkState.NetworkNone

    private fun onReceive() = with(getConnectivityStatus()) {
        if (this != stateLiveData.value) stateLiveData.postValue(this)
    }
}

sealed class SealedNetworkState {
    object NetworkWiFi : SealedNetworkState()
    object NetworkMobile : SealedNetworkState()
    object NetworkOther : SealedNetworkState()
    object NetworkNone : SealedNetworkState()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, check whether the internet available using:

```
private fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            when {
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Show a snack bar with settings option when there is no internet:

```
private fun showNoNetSnackbar() {
        val snack = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) // replace root view with your view Id
        snack.setAction("Settings") {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
        }
        snack.show()
    }
```

After enable WiFi then in onResume do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(!isConnectedToInternet()){
//Show snackbar..please tell me you know how to show a snackbar
}

private boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

Add this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: And if you need to add action to the snackbar use this https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html

Comment: thanks for this ....but I also want retry option in snackbar which again check for network if it found then goes to next activity ....pls help

Comment: Yeah so that is why if you need to add action in snackbar, see this link https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this hope it was helpful for you ,

---

```
 private boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

---

2. make method for **Snackbar**  and call it here

---

```
    if(!isConnectedToInternet()){
     showSnackBar("please check your internet connection",your_layout_name);
 }
public void showSnackBar(String string, LinearLayout linearLayout)
{
    snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(linearLayout, string, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).
                    setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            snackbar.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
    snackbar.show();
     }
```

---

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: but in the place of ok I want to put retry which check again the internet connection if user click on it

Comment: use the same as above that i said in "OK"
 if(!isConnectedToInternet()){
     showSnackBar("please check your internet connection","**here you have to pass the parent layout id**");
 }